# ReactJS: Radio button in a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I'm using reactstrap to create a form, but I have problem with the radio button because I don't understand how to save the value.

Variable of the form is:

```
const [formModel, setFormModel] = useState({
    name: '',
    deletedDate: '',
  });
```

My form is:

```
<AvForm model={formModel} onSubmit={filterResults} onReset={handleFormReset}>
<h3 className="text-center">Form</h3>
              <Row>
                <Col md="6">
                  <AvGroup>
                    <Label id="name" for="name">
                      Name
                    </Label>
                    <AvField
                      id="name"
                      data-cy="name"
                      type="text"
                      name="name"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      value={formModel.name}
                    />
                  </AvGroup>
<FormGroup check>
                      <Label check>
                        <Input
                          id="deletedDate"
                          data-cy="deletedDate"
                          type="radio"
                          name="deletedDate"
                          value="true"
                          onChange={handleChange}
                        />{' '}
                        Yes
                      </Label>
                    </FormGroup>
   <FormGroup check>
                      <Label check>
                        <Input
                          id="deletedDate"
                          data-cy="deletedDate"
                          type="radio"
                          name="deletedDate"
                          value="false"
                          onChange={handleChange}
                        />{' '}
                        No
                      </Label>
                    </FormGroup>
</AvGroup>
```

My filterResult is:

```
    const filterResults = (event, errors, values) => {
        console.log('values ', values);
        let entity = null;
        if (errors.length === 0) {
          entity = {
            ...values,
          };
        }
        //other code...

  const handleChange = e => {
    console.log('e ', e);
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    console.log('name ', name, ' value ', value);
    setFormModel(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };
```

Now when I submit the form, if I checked the deletedDate radiobutton in the filterResult function I don't have any value about it (but I have the value for the name)

How can I use the radio button in right way to save the value?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are missing the `checked` attribute:

```
 <label>
    <input
      id="deletedDate"
      data-cy="deletedDate"
      type="radio"
      name="deletedDate"
      value="true"
      checked={formModel.deletedDate === "true"}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />{" "}
    Yes
  </label>

  <label>
    <input
      id="deletedDate"
      data-cy="deletedDate"
      type="radio"
      name="deletedDate"
      value="false"
      checked={formModel.deletedDate === "false"}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />{" "}
    No
  </label>
```

[See it running in a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-cherry-zpj97?file=/src/App.js)

Edit: I have added a submit handler to the sandbox.

Comment: Thank you, you are right! But I have a problem why I can't see my variable's value in the filterResult? In the console log i see only the values of the other variables

Comment: I don't know what kind of component `AvForm` is, so I can't help you much with that. However, I added some submit handling to the sandbox. Take a look.